# RSPEC test failing. Any ideas?

Tags: ruby, rspec

The below is my test in RSPEC. It is failing and I can't figure out why! I am trying to get it to fill the van with bikes upto it's capacity but leave all the other bikes at the station. However it is deleting all the bikes except one in each at the moment.

```
let(:van) { Van.new }
let(:bike) { double :bike, broken?: false }
let(:broken_bike) { double :broken_bike, broken?: true }
let(:station) { double :station }

it 'can be filled with broken bikes' do
  station = double :station, { release_x_broken_bikes: broken_bike }
  expect(station).to receive(release_x_broken_bikes: broken_bike)
  van.fill_with_broken_bikes_from station
  expect(van.bike_count).to eq > 2
end
```

Relevant code in van.rb:

```
def initialize bikes = [], capacity = 10
    @bikes = bikes
    @capacity = capacity
end 

def bike_count 
    @bikes.count
end

def fill_with_broken_bikes_from station
    @bikes = station.release_x_broken_bikes(slots_available)
end

def slots_available
    @capacity - bike_count
end
```

Code in station.rb:

```
def broken_bikes
    @bikes.select { |bike| bike.broken? }
end

def release_broken_bike
    @bikes.delete(broken_bikes.first)
end

def release_x_broken_bikes(x)
    broken_bikes[0,x].map{ release_broken_bike}
end
```

Comment: can you post the errors.

Comment: Is `x.to eq > 2` the right way to do this?

Comment: Failures:

  1) Van can be filled with broken bikes
     Failure/Error: van.fill_with_broken_bikes_from station
       Double :station received unexpected message :release_x_broken_bikes with (10)
     # ./lib/van.rb:29:in `fill_with_broken_bikes_from'
     # ./spec/van_spec.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00995 seconds
12 examples, 1 failure

Comment: @tadman almost certainly not, I was just trying things to see what it returned.

Answer (score 0):

In your spec:

```
expect(station).to receive(release_x_broken_bikes: broken_bike)
```

You're telling the station to expect to receive a `release_x_broken_bikes` with an argument of `broken_bike`?  Looking at the method, it wants a number.  `broken_bike` looks like a double to me.

Your error tells you exactly this:

> 1) Van can be filled with broken bikes Failure/Error: van.fill_with_broken_bikes_from station Double :station received unexpected message :release_x_broken_bikes with (10) # ./lib/van.rb:29:in fill_with_broken_bikes_from' # ./spec/van_spec.rb:51:in block (2 levels) in ' Finished in 0.00995 seconds 12 examples, 1 failure

It received a call to `release_x_broken_bikes` with `10`, which seems to be what you should actually want.  Tell it to expect that, and you can get to your next problem (if there is one).